# Run PHP Artisan in background

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, process, laravel-artisan

I try to create daemon in PHP. I have Artisan command, but I can't run it in background.

For simple command is `php aritsan run:daemon`.

I tried to use

```
exec('php artisan run:daemon &');
```

And it's working fine, I have extra process in background, but my actual process is still waiting for response. When I kill it by `CTRL+C` or in another way, second process still running in background. The same effect I have with `Symfony\Process` when I use

```
$process=new Process("php artisan run:daemon");
$process->start();
```

But I don't want to kill process, I want to execute one command and then this command run process in background and after this will close yourself. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Put it [on the queue](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#calling-commands-via-code):

```php
Artisan::queue('run:daemon');
```

Comment: When I use this method script doesn't wait and doesn't run in background, but it's like a overlay for my another CLI command.